# A6 printing error

Tags: printing

I want to print out some vignettes in A6. I made the pageformat to A6 and when When I trying to print it out it ejects the blank paper. I tried with an A4 paper, too and it prints this on the paper:

```
Internal ERROR - IllegalMediaSize
Position: 0x0 (0)
System: h6fw_5.51/xl_tbl
Line: 685
Version: SPL 5.51 03-28-2011
```

What can I do?

Comment: From what application are you trying to print? Which printer? Does printing from other application work?

Comment: From LibreOffice, Samsung SXC3000 Series. If I print A4, the printing is work, if I print other size, it prints out this message